# How to set reffer in header in Nextjs

Tags: next.js, header, http-referer

I want to display some images in my next js project https://zjcdn.mangahere.org/store/manga/106/00-001.1/compressed/s02.jpg but it need a custom referer to access the image "Referer": "http://www.mangahere.cc/manga/one_piece/v00/c001.1/1.html"

I tried to fetch the image link by using fetch(url, option) method but it didn't worked.
I want to display 20 to 30 image like this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.